# How do I force www in URL along with the Patrol plugin to force https

Tags: htaccess, ssl

I'm using the Patrol plugin to force https in the domain, but I also need to force www into the URL. When I do that with some htaccess rewrite rules I found online I get an error when I try to load the site that there's too many redirects happening.

This is my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this was the code to force WWW that I was trying unsuccessfully to use that resulted in the "too many redirects" error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#force www in URL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\.adacore\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.adacore.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm not sure how or if the Patrol plugin (https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.patrol) factors into the htaccess file to be honest. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is how our default `.htaccess` with https redirect and forced `www.` for all our projects looks like. So if you have the url `example.com` you'll get redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
Action application/x-httpd-php70 /cgi-sys/php70-fcgi-starter.fcgi
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php70
```